# jQuery slidedown menu trigger makes menu slideup too quickly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following html:

```
     <div class="col-sm-12" id='dropdown_menu_group'>
        <div id='dropdown_library_menu'>
            <div class="row" id='dropdown_menu_row'>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <a class='button-text btn' id='library_button' href="{{pathFor 'library'}}">my library</a>
                </div>
                <div class='col-sm-2 col-sm-pull-1' id='google_drive_text'>
                    GOOGLE DRIVE
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2" id='settings_button'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id='dropdown_library_menu_border'></div>
    </div>
```

my `id='dropdown_library_menu'` is hidden by default, and the div below it `<div id='dropdown_library_menu_border'></div>` has opacity of 0, so that when it is scrolled over, it makes the `id='dropdown_library_menu'` slide down.  The issue is, though, that `<div id='dropdown_library_menu_border'></div>` is still there when the menu slides down, and thus, when I scroll over the opacity 0 div that triggers the slideDown (inside of the menu, at this point), it tricks my jQuery into thinking this condition is met:

```
'mouseout #dropdown_library_menu': function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('#dropdown_library_menu').slideUp('slow');
}
```

Because technically, I am mousing out of the dropdown menu and into the dropdown menu trigger.

I want to make the blank div move to the bottom of the menu when the `slideDown` is triggered, but setting `position relative` on the parent and `position absolute` on the children totally messes up my webpage.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle example?

Comment: i just tried...didnt work.  this is a portion of a page in a webapp that has a couple js packages in it

Answer (score 3):

You can make it even slower,

```
'mouseout #dropdown_library_menu': function(ev){
 ev.preventDefault();
 $('#dropdown_library_menu').slideUp(3000); // Slide up in 3 seconds,
 }
```

Comment: ...what?  that doesnt make any sense

Comment: Just can't imagine how your layouts are arranged. Please tell me what is "blank div" in your question ? is that the same div with opacity 0 ?

Comment: I hacked a solution together and have to move on unfortunately.  you seem to have gotten some good (random?) love for your answer though

Comment: That's why you need to "title" the question properly..! That's the most expected answer for your title. . ha ha.